# replacement characters http response

Tags: c, http, proxy

I'm writing a proxy server and using nc to test it.

Since i'm manually sending GET requests the headers are like this:

```
GET / HTTP/1.0  
Host: www.amazon.com  
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:10.0.3) Gecko/20120305 Firefox/10.0.3  
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8  
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate  
Connection: close  
Proxy-Connection: close
```

There is a \r\n at the very end so the headers are going through fine. However, when I go to read the response from Amazon the response headers are normal but the content lines are all replacement characters.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK  
Date: Tue, 25 Nov 2014 17:08:03 GMT  
Server: Server  
Set-Cookie: skin=noskin; path=/; domain=.amazon.com  
pragma: no-cache  
x-amz-id-1: 157CTXPNTVVD271HDG44  
p3p: policyref="http://www.amazon.com/w3c/p3p.xml",CP="CAO DSP LAW CUR ADM IVAo IVDo CONo OTPo OUR     DELi PUBi OTRi BUS PHY ONL UNI PUR FIN COM NAV INT DEM CNT STA HEA PRE LOC GOV OTC "  
cache-control: no-cache  
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN  
expires: -1  
x-amz-id-2: ggo8s1NmVFVscFO6Blt05UzTxs2CbsdYzcw4z8TyYLiDv0QbFSdQFK09JncUcB/w  
Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent  
Content-Encoding: gzip  
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8  
Set-cookie: x-wl-uid=1LX2gl15WltBK6y/zMT25z7xYeDp5fpb2FPgX2jI1wrLmoHlSfdF5DpdOHjIqmuMZyWTgPxM/t6k=; path=/; domain=.amazon.com; expires=Tue, 01-Jan-2036 08:00:01 GMT  
Set-cookie: session-id-time=2082787201l; path=/; domain=.amazon.com; expires=Tue, 01-Jan-2036 08:00:01 GMT  
Set-cookie: session-id=182-1331589-3819822; path=/; domain=.amazon.com; expires=Tue, 01-Jan-2036 08:00:01 GMT  
Connection: close
```

The body follows as

```
O�xW6m�����Y=  
�   -�X��?0!p!������4j�f��X�J            
                              ��YɴyOT�Q�M�w�$�|K�fux(���,S�!��
```

I have no idea why this is happening - at first I thought it would be something to do with the Accept headers, however those were given to me in a hand out to use so I don't think that is the issue.

Answer (score 1):

The content encoding is `gzip`, which means the content needs to be unzipped.

Comment: I think the issue was actually just the fact that it was binary data from like an image or video or something rather than text that I thought I should be getting. Other sites work just fine.